# PowerBI Cloud vs PowerBi Desktop different Culture settings

Tags: powerbi, culture

My Language/Culture Settings of my PowerBI Desktop Document result in decimals being shown as periods. When uploaded to PowerBI Cloud I see commas instead. Is there a way to force PowerBI Cloud to use the same culture? Or can the PowerBI Cloud culter be set somewhere?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a regional settings area within PowerBi desktop.  Have you looked there?  I’m wondering if there is a setting there to change that.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In power query you can force the decimal plates locale.

Open power query, select the desired column and change the column type to decimal number.
Then open the advanced editor and add the locale string to the script at this step. For instance:

```
#"Type production" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Rename",{{"sales.production", type number}}, "en-US")
```

Just add one more argument (eg.: `"En-US"`) with the locale at the end of `Table.TransformColumnType`